# Separating the groups of bar chart in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

In the following code I have two groups of bar charts, each has 5 bars. The problem is they are combined and very close together. how should I separate two groups of bar chart from each other?

```
    X = np.arange(2)
    barWidth = 0.25
    plt.bar(X + 0.00, Unf1_list, color = 'b', width = 0.2,align='center')
    plt.bar(X + 0.25, Unf2_list, color = 'g', width = 0.2,align='center')
    plt.bar(X + 0.50, Unf3_list, color = 'r', width = 0.2,align='center')
    plt.bar(X + 0.75, Unf4_list, color = 'y', width = 0.2,align='center')
    plt.bar(X + 1.00, Unf5_list, color = 'gray', width = 0.2,align='center')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xticks([r + barWidth for r in range(2)], ['z=1', 'z=6'])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to reduce the barwidth, so the groups are more separated

```
barWidth = 0.15
barSep = 0.01

for i, lst in enumerate([lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4, lst5]):
    plt.bar(X + i*(barWidth+barSep), lst, width=barWidth, color=f'C{i}')

plt.yscale('log')
plt.xticks([r + barWidth for r in range(2)], ['z=1', 'z=6'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[After I posted my answer, I noticed that a quite similar answer was posted just earlier. I also noted the other post didn't address the positioning of the ticks.]

In the code of the OP, `fig.update_layout(bargap=..., bargroupgap=...)` will not work, because the distances are set manually. The original settings don't work because the last bar of the first group is placed on the same place as the first bar of the second group.

My approach would be to calculate the barwidth via the number of bars, and the desired gaps. This also allows to calculate the exact center to place the xticks.

```py
Unf1_list = [24, 25]
Unf2_list = [14, 15]
Unf3_list = [94, 95]
Unf4_list = [22, 23]
Unf5_list = [4, 5]
ys = [Unf1_list, Unf2_list, Unf3_list, Unf4_list, Unf5_list]

X = np.arange(2)
num_bars_in_group = len(ys)
gap_between_bargroups = 0.15  # where 1.0 means the distance between the first bar of a group to the first of the next
gap_between_bars_in_group = 0.03

bar_width = ((1.0 - gap_between_bargroups) + gap_between_bars_in_group) / num_bars_in_group

#colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'y', 'gray']
colors = ['#7fc97f','#beaed4','#fdc086','#ffff99','#386cb0']

for i, (y, c) in enumerate(zip(ys, colors)):
    plt.bar(X + i*bar_width, y, color=c, width=bar_width - gap_between_bars_in_group, align='center')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xticks([r + bar_width * (num_bars_in_group - 1) / 2 for r in range(2)], ['z=1', 'z=6'])
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]